# webdriver.io browser.debug() not working in async function. Why isn't it?

Tags: javascript, webdriver

A simplified view ~

Works in this instance:

```
it("should confirm the the prop", () => {
  browser.debug() // works fine
})
```

Doesn't work in this instance:

```
it("should confirm the the prop", async() => {
  browser.debug() // doesn't `freeze` the driven browser for debugging
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though this has baffled me for some time, the second I publicize the question, an answer pops in. `browser.debug()` requires an `await`.

Now it works:

```
it("should confirm the the prop", async() => {
  await browser.debug()
})
```